# Disintegration of a push forward measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ and $\nu$ two probabilites on $\mathbb{R}^{d}$.

Let $T : \mathbb{R}^{d} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{d}$ a mesurable map such that $T_{\ast} \mu = \nu$. 
I can disintegrate $\gamma := (id,T)_{\ast} \mu$ according to $(h, h_{\ast} \gamma$), I get a familly of measure $\gamma_{y}$ concentred on $h^{-1}(\{y\})$ as usually. But this time $\gamma$ have a special form. So do you think it can give me information about $\gamma_{y}$ ?

And with more generalities what do we get when we disintegrate a push forward measure $\gamma := f_{\ast}\mu$ according $(h, h_{\ast} \gamma)$ ?

Any help would be apprecieted, thanks and regards.

EDIT : As I have no answer, I'll try to be more specific, my question is, do we have $\gamma_{y} := (id,S)_{\#}\omega$ with $\omega$ a measure.
I think $\omega$ could be a disintegration of $\mu$.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking. What is $h$? What does 'disintegration according to $(h, h_{\#}\gamma)$' mean?

Comment: What about $T_{\#}\mu = \nu$? Wouldn't $T_{\#}\mu$ live on $\mathbb{R}$, not $\mathbb{R}^d$?

Comment: Oh I see, I edited,  $T : \mathbb{R}^{d} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{d}$ not  $T : \mathbb{R}^{d} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ obiously.

Comment: Thanks. You still need to address Steve's questions.

Comment: The map $(id,T)$ is an isomorphism of measure spaces, so that its conditional measures are just $\delta$-measures.

Comment: Rokhlin, 1952 found a case in which a disintegration is always possible. The statement of the theorem can be found on Wikipedia : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disintegration_theorem

Comment: That is exactly what I called 'disintegration according to (h,h#γ)'

Comment: @CechMS What is the Rokhlin 1952 result? There is no mention of Rokhlin in the cited Wikipedia article.

Comment: What I called 'disintegration according to (h,h#γ)' is the statement of the theorem which can be found on wiki.

Comment: I edited if someone wants to give me a help.

Comment: Perhaps it helps if I tell you why I am still struggling to understand the question: In the Wikipedia article you link there are 2 measures, $\mu$ and $\nu$, with $\nu = \mu \circ \pi^{-1}$. This would fit the objects in your question if $\mu=\mu$, $\nu=\gamma$ and $\pi = (id, T)$. So what is $h$, and in particular, why do you specify a tuple $(h, h_{\#}\gamma)$ which has one entry a function, and one entry a measure?

Comment: Let $(X, {\mathcal X},\mu)$ and $(Y, {\mathcal Y},\nu)$ be probability spaces, with $(X,{\mathcal X})$ regular. Let $\pi: X \to Y$ be a morphism (thus $\nu = \pi_\# \mu$). Then there exists a probability kernel $y \mapsto \mu_y$ such that
$$
\int_X f (g \circ \pi)\ d\mu = \int_Y (\int_X f\ d\mu_y) g(y)\ d\nu(y) 
$$
for any bounded measurable $f: X \to {\Bbb C}$ and $g: Y \to {\Bbb C}$. Also, for any such $g$, we have
$$
g \circ \pi = g(y) \mu_y-a.e. 
$$
for $\nu$-a.e. $y$.

Comment: Furthermore, this probability kernel is unique up to \nu-almost everywhere equivalence, in the sense that if $y \mapsto \mu'_y$ is another probability kernel with the same properties, then $\mu_y = \mu'_y$ for $\nu$-almost every $y$.

Comment: Here $\pi = h$ and $\mu = \gamma$ and $\nu = h_{\#}\mu$

Comment: And about my post, we are in a very special case because here $\gamma$ is already a pushfoward measure. That's the point. I think we can say something in that special case. But we can disintegrate any probability, pushforward or not, it doesn't matter as long as you disintegrate according to $(\pi, \mu)$ in the theorem above. (which was taken from  Tao's Blog).

Comment: I think I see now what you mean. In more probabilistic terms: We disintegrate the measure $\theta = (h, id)_{\#}\gamma$ where $h$ is some function. And the disintegration is as $\theta = (h_{\#} \gamma) \otimes \gamma_y$, and the question is what kind of properties $\gamma_y$ satisfies?

Comment: Yes indeed, I'm glad it is clear now. I even got a idea of what $\gamma_{y}$ could look like, it could be $\gamma_{y} := (id,S)_{\#}\omega$ with $\omega$ a measure (to be more specific a disintegration of $\mu$). But any properties as you said could help :) (Because I can't say anything about $\gamma_{y}$ in general and even in that special case).

Comment: It would help if you clearly state which maps and which measures you are considering. Aren't you looking at the image of the measure $\mu$ under the map $x\mapsto (x,Tx)$?

Comment: Yes indeed of course !

Answer (score 0):

I found something, not exactly what I need, maybe it could be a good start.

If $\gamma = \gamma_{y} \oplus \alpha_{\#} \gamma$ the disintegration of $\gamma$ according to $(\alpha, \alpha_{\#})$.
Then $\beta_{\#}\gamma = \beta_{\#} \gamma_{y} \oplus \alpha_{\#} \gamma$

Now let $ \beta_{\#}\gamma = \mu_{y} \oplus \delta_{\#} \beta_{\#}\gamma$ the disintegration of $\beta_{\#} \gamma$ according to $(\delta, \delta_{\#} \beta_{\#} \gamma)$ then

$$
 \mu_{y} = \beta_{\#} \gamma_{y}
$$

I hope someone will answer...